# multiple endpoints dagger2 retrofit

Tags: java, api, retrofit2, dagger-2, endpoint

for my project I need to use 2 different API endpoints. Now I have implemented dagger2 code which works with only 1 endpoint. Does any one know, how can I add another endpoint here in my code properly?

Here is my Application file:

```
public class TalisProjectApplication extends Application {

@Inject
DataManager dataManager;
ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this, FirebaseService.ENDPOINT, FirebaseService.ENDPOINT_ADS))
            .build();
    applicationComponent.inject(this);
}

public static TalisProjectApplication get(Context context) {
    return (TalisProjectApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
}

public ApplicationComponent getComponent() {
    return applicationComponent;
}
```

}

Here is my dagger2 file

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
protected final Application application;
String baseUrl;
String baseAdsUrl;
private LoginActivity activity;

public static final String FIREBASE = "firebase";
public static final String ADS = "ads";

public ApplicationModule(Application app, @Named(FIREBASE) String url, @Named(ADS)String baseAdsUrl) {
    application = app;
    this.baseUrl = url;
    this.baseAdsUrl = baseAdsUrl;
}

@Provides
Application provideApplication() {
    return application;
}

@Provides
@ApplicationContext
Context provideContext() {
    return application;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
    return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Cache provideHttpCache(Application application) {
    int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
    return cache;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
Gson provideGson() {
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    return gsonBuilder.create();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient(Cache cache) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.addInterceptor(logging);
    client.cache(cache);
    return client.build();
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named(FIREBASE)
Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(baseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

}


@Provides
@Singleton
@Named(ADS)
Retrofit provideAdsRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(baseAdsUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named(FIREBASE)
FirebaseService.Firebase providesTheFirebaseService(@Named(FIREBASE) Retrofit retrofit) {
    return retrofit.create(FirebaseService.Firebase.class);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
@Named(ADS)
FirebaseService.Firebase providesTheAdsService(@Named(ADS) Retrofit retrofit) {
    return retrofit.create(FirebaseService.Firebase.class);
}
}
```

Here is my Service file where I use retrofit calls:

```
public class FirebaseService {

public static final String ENDPOINT = "";
public static final String ENDPOINT_ADS = "";
private static FirebaseService.Firebase firebase;

public interface Firebase {

}
}
```

After my try to implement another endpoint. This error now appears:

> retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor
>   or from an @Provides-annotated method.

**EDIT**

```
@Singleton
public class DataManager {

private Retrofit firebaseRetrofit;
private Retrofit adsRetrofit;
private FirebaseService.Firebase firebase;
private DatabaseReference databaseRef;
private Application application;
private PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper;

String catId;
@Inject
public DataManager(@Named(FIREBASE) Retrofit firebaseRetrofit, @Named(ADS) Retrofit adsRetrofit, FirebaseService.Firebase firebase, Application application, PreferencesHelper preferencesHelper) {
    this.firebaseRetrofit = firebaseRetrofit;
    this.adsRetrofit = adsRetrofit;
    this.firebase = firebase;
    this.application = application;
    this.preferencesHelper = preferencesHelper;
}
}
```

Comment: Show the code, where you `@Inject` `Retrofit` instances.

Comment: Using only one retrofit url, I injected Retrofit instances in my data manager. You can see it in EDIT. I did not use @Inject annotation and it worked without it

Answer (score 1):

```
@Inject
public DataManager(Retrofit retrofit, ...) {
    ...
}
```

Well, now Dagger is confused, because he cannot know what `Retrofit` to provide to your `DataManager`.

You have declared two `@Named` `Retrofit` instances in your module. Now you have to specify which exactly `Retrofit` instance you want to be passed to `DataManager`:

```
@Inject
public DataManager(@Named(FIREBASE) Retrofit firebaseRetrofit,
                   @Named(ADS) Retrofit adsRetrofit,
                   ... ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! now this error appears:
error: my.github.tomas.talisproject.data.remote.FirebaseService.Firebase cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: See how you provide `Firebase` instance in your module. You have annotated it with `@Named(FIREBASE)`, it means you have to annotate it in the constructor parameter also.

Comment: azizbekian thank you for your help, I edited everything you said in my post, but still the same error appears...

Comment: @LaurisMacke, `I edited everything you said in my post` you haven't. Change to `@Named(FIREBASE) FirebaseService.Firebase firebase`.